# Interaction between Beamer, Nicematrix and Polyglossia

Tags: beamer, polyglossia, block, nicematrix

I have run into a curious interaction between Nicematrix and Polyglossia when used in Beamer, specifically in connection with the command \Block. The code shown compiles perfectly in XeLaTeX if the command \setotherlanguages{arabic} is commented out, but when the comment is erased and the code recompiled (more than three times), what we get is what is shown in the image.[image: Results when \setotherlanguages{arabic} is activestrong text]

```
\documentclass[11pt,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,gensymb,siunitx,units}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary {intersections,arrows.meta,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing,trees,backgrounds,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}



\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{float,wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../ImgLinEng/}}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}



\setmainfont{Bodoni 72}[
    SmallCapsFont={Caslon Book BE},
    ]
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{American Typewriter}


\newfontfamily\ipafont{Doulos SIL}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Naskh Arabic}


\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Mean values for $F_{1}$ and $F_{2}$ of Central Catalan vowels}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{lrr}
\CodeBefore \rowcolor{gray!9}{1-2}
\Body
\toprule
\Block[c]{1-3}{Central Catalan}\\
\Block[c]{1-1}{Vowel} & \Block[c]{1-1}{$F_{1}$} & \Block[c]{1-1}{$F_{2}$}\\\midrule
{\ipafont [i]} & \SI{334}{\hertz} & \SI{2078}{\hertz}\\
{\ipafont [u]} & \SI{394}{\hertz} & \SI{960}{\hertz}\\
{\ipafont [o]} & \SI{489}{\hertz} & \SI{1047}{\hertz}\\
{\ipafont [ɔ]} & \SI{608}{\hertz} & \SI{1125}{\hertz}\\
{\ipafont [a]} & \SI{730}{\hertz} & \SI{1358}{\hertz}\\
{\ipafont [ɛ]} & \SI{581}{\hertz} & \SI{1700}{\hertz}\\
{\ipafont [e]} & \SI{450}{\hertz} & \SI{1839}{\hertz}\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide a more compact MWE (minimal working example). In particular, it's difficult to compile your code since it uses some non standard fonts such as `Caslon Book BE`.